# Page Public Content Access\', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is my code:

```
var getPageToken = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/'+pageid+'…;

request(getPageToken, function(errorPageToken, responsePageToken) {

console.log(errorPageToken);
console.log(responsePageToken);

});
```

For few pages I'm getting the Page Token. Whereas, with few pages I'm getting the below error.

Error:

```
Page Public Content Access\', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook
```

Few pages have access via Business Manager, few pages have access via personal account. In both cases I'm facing the issue, its very random and I'm unable to identify the cause, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the actual call that returns that error response? Guessing by your code snippet you use a page token? Guessing by that error response you try to query a page using an app token? Can you please provide that missing info (what call does return that error and what type of token you use)?

Comment: @lars.schwarz I'm trying to fetch page insights. It's possible only with a Page Token, not User Token.

Comment: So what is your actual call? The snippet you provide has nothing to do with retrieving page insights.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out that the problem was with the `access_token` I was passing to retrieve the `pageid`.

I had multiple accounts set up to fetch data. While linking the page with `access_token` I made a mistake.

That was the cause for the error.